# how to print custom stacktrace in java logback?

Tags: logback

Current logback.xml

```
<appender name="FILEOUT3" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>D:/${byDay}.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5level %msg%replace(%xException){"\n", ">> "}%nopex%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Current result :

```
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
>> at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:92) ~[play_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>> at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:570) ~[play_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>> at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:252) ~[play-jdbc_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
```

I want result :

```
[12:43:16.454] play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
[12:43:16.454]    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:92) ~[play_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
[12:43:16.454]    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:570) ~[play_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
[12:43:16.454]    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:252) ~[play-jdbc_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
:
:
more 40 lines
:
[12:43:16.454]    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:252) ~[play-jdbc_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
```

IMPORTANT! 
Same Time Print

I want know.
How to change logback.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this by changing only logback.xml, because ReplacingCompositeConverter, which is called by %replace, uses only static strings as replacements (no dates or any other conversion words of PatternLayout).

To reach your goal you should create custom converter (if you'll use mine, notice that it should be placed in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern package)

```
package ch.qos.logback.core.pattern;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout;

import ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Node;
import ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.ScanException;

public class ReplacingAndParsingCompositeConverter<E> extends ReplacingCompositeConverter<E> {

    @Override
    protected String transform(E event, String in) {
        if (!started) {
            return in;
        }

        String parsedReplacement;

        try {
            Parser<E> p = new Parser<E>(replacement);
            p.setContext(getContext());
            Node t = p.parse();
            Converter<E> c = p.compile(t, PatternLayout.defaultConverterMap);
            ConverterUtil.setContextForConverters(getContext(), c);
            ConverterUtil.startConverters(c);
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            while (c != null) {
                c.write(buf, event);
                c = c.getNext();
            }
            parsedReplacement = buf.toString();
        } catch (ScanException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            parsedReplacement = replacement;
        }
        return pattern.matcher(in).replaceAll(parsedReplacement);
    }
}
```

Then you should declare this converter in logback.xml with <conversionRule/> and use it instead of old %replace.

```
<configuration ...>
    <conversionRule conversionWord="replaceAndParse" converterClass="ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.ReplacingAndParsingCompositeConverter" />

    <appender name="FILEOUT3" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>D:/${byDay}.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>[%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5level %msg%replaceAndParse(%xException){"(\r?\n)", "$1[%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}]"}%nopex%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    ....
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks! can you make simple code send to me? epikxm@gmail.com / and I'm sorry. my english isn't so good.

Comment: replacement / pattern error :( how to fix source code?

Comment: Could you clarify your comment? I'm not sure I follow you.

Comment: What kind of code do you expect? All required code is in answer. To make it work you have to use logback-core (I tried with 1.1.3) and logback-classic of same version. Anything else is not required.

Comment: I made small example project, you may see it here - https://github.com/eugenius/logback-parsed-replacing-converter-example . You may run it with `mvn clean verify`

Comment: Thank you very much !! Your Good Man !!